# Plugin wordpress genera archivo excel

Tags: php, wordpress, excel, wordpress-plugin

estoy creando un plugin en wordpress que debería descargarme un excel con varios datos de la BD pero en vez de hacerlo, pega la tabla dentro del dashboard de Wordpress.

```
<?php
 /**
 * Plugin Name: Excel
 * Plugin URI: http://
 * Description: 
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author:          
 * Author URI:      https://
 * License: GNU/GPLv3 http://
 */

function twitt_options_panel() {
  $parent_slug = null;

  $parent_slug = "excel";
  $page = add_menu_page('Excel', 'Excel', 'Excel PostVenta', 'excel', WD_WDTI_URL . '/images/new.png');
    add_action('admin_print_styles-' . $page, 'styles');
    add_action('admin_print_scripts-' . $page, 'scripts');

 $plugins_page = add_submenu_page($parent_slug, 'Excel Preventa', 'Excel Puntos de Venta', 'manage_options', 'exportarventa', 'excel');

  $plugins_page = add_submenu_page($parent_slug, 'Excel Preventa', 'Excel Puntos de Servicio', 'manage_options', 'exportarservicio', 'excel');

}

add_action('admin_menu', 'options_panel',9);

function  excel() {

       if($_GET['page']=='exportarventa'){

        include('excelventa.php');

       }

        if($_GET['page']=='exportarservicio'){

      include('excelservicio.php');

       }
}

function integration_activate() {
  $version = get_option("WD_WDTI_VERSION_FREE");
  if($version == false){
    add_option("WD_WDTI_VERSION_FREE" , WD_WDTI_VERSION_FREE);
  }
  global $wpdb;
}
 register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'integration_activate');

?>
```

He creado dos enlaces para cargar 'excelservicio.php' o 'excelventa.php' según el botón que pulses, por si acaso era problema del propio plugin, pero ni así funciona. Lo raro es que este código funcionaba perfectamente desde el frontend de la página.

(He obviado las consultas porque los resultados salen correctos, el problema es que no genera el excel)

```html
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Coordenadas.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");





echo '<table border="1" bordercolor="#D2D2D2" cellspacing="20">';



$continente = array(77,2595,2594,80,202,76,121);
 
 echo '<tr border="0">
 
 <th border="0" colspan="9"><h1>PUNTOS DE VENTA</h1></th>
 
 </tr>';
 
 echo utf8_decode('<tr>
  <th>id</th>
  <th>Empresa</th>
  <th>Continente</th>  
  <th>Localidad</th>
  <th>Dirección</th>
  <th>Latitud</th>
  <th>Longitud</th>
  <th>Teléfono</th>
  <th>Móvil</th>
  <th>Teléfono 24</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Web</th>
  <th>Contacto</th>
  <th>Carrocería</th> 
  <th>Integral</th> 
  </tr>');
    
    
    
    echo'<tr>
<td>'.$id.'</td>
<td>'.$empresa.'</td>
<td>'.$nombre_conti['name'].'</td>
<td>'.$datos_venta['name'].'</td>
<td>'.$direccion.'</td>
<td>"'.$latitud.'"</td>
<td>"'.$longitud.'"</td>
<td>"'.$telefono.'"</td>
<td>"'.$movil.'"</td>
<td>"'.$telefono24.'"</td>
<td>'.$email.'</td>
<td>'.$web.'</td>
<td>'.$nombre.'</td>
<td>'.$existecarroceria.'</td>
<td>'.$existesobrechasis.'</td>

</tr>';

echo'</table>';
```